# Главный по местности на жаргоне

Tags: жаргон

Как на жаргоне говорят о руководителе по точке, по определенной территории? О том, кто управляет всеми местными торгашами, нелегально сбывающими продукцию, кто отвечает за содеянные поступки, случаи, происшедшие в определенных территориальных пределах?

Answer (score 1):

Такого человека называют "смотрящий".

Исторически смотрящим мог быть лишь назначенец, поставленный ворами в законе. Но после хаоса 90-х этот термин стал использоваться и в расширенном смысле: скажем, руководитель группировки назначает своего смотрящего за бизнесом или за территорией. Однако такоe словоупотребление содержит в себе уклонение от изначального, строго воровского, значения.